# Get input value on keyup Vuejs 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to get the input value on keyup using Vuejs 2 but always get an empty result like the data. Please see code below.

HTML:

```
<input type="email" @keyup="this.$data.email= $event.target.value" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Username (your work email)">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block inactive" @click="submit">Log in</button>
```

Script:

```
data () {
  return {
    email: '',
  }
},
methods: {
  submit () {
    alert(this.$data.email)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to reference `email` (not `this.$data.email`):

```
<input type="email" @keyup="email = $event.target.value" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Username (your work email)">
```

---

But also, why not use `v-model` to bind `email` to the input?

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
    }
  },
  methods: {
    submit () {
      alert(this.email)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="email" v-model="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Username (your work email)">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block inactive" @click="submit">Log in</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyup.enter.native="submitMETHOD"
```

Comment: Please include a brief description of your suggestions.